# How do I prompt the user for integers to multiply?

Tags: ruby, user-input

Okay, so I'm trying to make a very simple program in ruby and I keep running into errors. I don't want answers directly, but I would like guidance because it's for school and I'm not a fan of cheating. I am writing a simple program where the user puts in the length and width of their iPhone screen and then the program will multiply the area by 326. 326 is the pixels-per-inch (PPI) of the resolution, and then that value multiplied by (length x width) would give the total pixels on the screen.

What I have so far:

```
l = gets.to_i

w = gets.to_i

print "What is the length of the screen?"
#(dont know how to get them to enter it)

print "What is the width?"
#(same as line before dont know how to get them to enter it)

result = 326(l*w)
```

Thats all I have and would appreciate any help, just don't give me the entire program, please!

Comment: `gets.to_i` - doesn't this prompt the user?

Comment: I think any google search and/or reading about Ruby will help you with this, after all what you want it's to learn no? Here is something to start with: http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print the prompt message BEFORE calling `gets` so the prompt message is on the screen while they are typing.

This line is incorrect:

```
result = 326(l*w)
```

Unlike in math, in Ruby you can't just put two numbers next to each other and expect them to be multiplied.  You have to use the `*` (asterisk) to multiply.  So you will need a total of two asterisks on that line.

You should use `puts` at the end to print out the result.

Answer (score 1):

### Prompt First, Then Collect Your Data Value

You need to issue your prompt before you try to populate a variable with the reply. For example:

```
PPI = 326

print 'Length: '
length = gets.to_i

print 'Width: '
width = gets.to_i

resolution = length * width * PPI
puts "Resolution: #{resolution}"
```

You also need to use the correct multiplication [operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm), which is the asterisk. You can then do whatever you like with the value; in this case, I chose to interpolate it with a string for output to the user.